# How to 'mirror' live webcam video when using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to have two different outputs of webcam videos, one being the normal webcam footage and the other to be the "mirrored" version of it.  Is that possible with OpenCV?

```py
import time, cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
a = 0
while True:
    a = a+1
    check, frame = video.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("Capturing", gray)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

print(a)

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, Yes it is possible using cv2. I have made some modification in your code to make it happen.

```
# Loading modules
import cv2
import numpy as np     # Numpy module will be used for horizontal stacking of two frames

video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
a=0
while True:
    a=a+1
    check, frame= video.read()

    # Converting the input frame to grayscale
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   

    # Fliping the image as said in question
    gray_flip = cv2.flip(gray,1)

    # Combining the two different image frames in one window
    combined_window = np.hstack([gray,gray_flip])

    # Displaying the single window
    cv2.imshow("Combined videos ",combined_window)
    key=cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key==ord('q'):
        break
print(a)

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Hope you get what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

to get the mirror image:

```
flip_img = cv2.flip(img,1)
```

Comment: excerpt of previously given answer, with variables renamed.